# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on C loop with pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

I keep getting a segmentation fault on the following code and cannot figure out why.
Please help me fix it.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "tempo.h"

int num_thread = 12;

//int ini[20];

//time_t start, end;
int threadShare;
int end = 127;
int start = 32;
void *loop(void *arg);

pthread_t *m;

void
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    double qt = (((double) end - (double) start) / (double) num_thread);

    threadShare = round(qt);

    m = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * num_thread);

    int ptStart[num_thread + 1];

    // creates the pthreads and divides the work
    for (int i = 0; i < num_thread; i++) {

        pthread_create(&m[i], NULL, loop, (void *) &ptStart[i]);
        ptStart[i + 1] = ptStart[i] + threadShare;

        // i, ptStart[i]);

    }
    // closes the pthreads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_thread; i++) {
        pthread_join(ptStart[i], NULL);
    }

}

void *
loop(void *arg)
{
    //password to be broken
    char senha[40] = "!!!#(,4#";
    char linha[40];

    // 8 loops parsing through the ascii characters
    for (char v1 = 32; v1 < 127; v1++) {
        linha[0] = v1;
        for (char v2 = 32; v2 < 127; v2++) {
            linha[1] = v2;
            for (char v3 = 32; v3 < 127; v3++) {
                linha[2] = v3;
                for (char v4 = 32; v4 < 127; v4++) {
                    linha[3] = v4;
                    for (char v5 = 32; v5 < 126; v5++) {
                        linha[4] = v5;
                        for (char v6 = 32; v6 < 127; v6++) {
                            linha[5] = v6;
                            for (char v7 = 32; v7 < 127; v7++) {
                                linha[6] = v7;
                                for (char v8 = 32; v8 < 127; v8++) {
                                    linha[7] = v8;

                                    printf("%s\n", linha);

                                    // compares the password with the
                                    // characters parsed in the loop
                                    int ok = strcmp(senha, linha);

                                    if (ok == 0) {
                                        exit(0);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code should divide the task of brute forcing a password among a variable number of pthreads. I am a newbie at c and cannot figure out the issue.
I am pretty sure the issue occurs inside the loop, as v1 will iterate through the ascii characters before the segmentation fault occurs.

Edit: Tried to clean up the code a little, alas i am a total beginner with c

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: This isn't code, this is chaos. Can you clean it up so we have some idea what's going on here?

Comment: You have UB (undefined behavior). `linha` is function scoped (on the stack), so it is _uninitialized_. Thus, it can have random values. And, you do _not_ terminate the `linha` string/array with 0. So, `printf("%s\n", linha);` can have UB [and can segfault]. Likewise, for the `strcmp` [`senha` is properly terminated but, again, `linha` is _not_]. For starters, change `char linha[40];` into `char linha[40] = { 0 };` to initialize it. Now, all chars in it start with 0 (the string terminator char). Or, just before the `printf`, do: `linha[8] = 0;`

Comment: At least following point need to correct: ` i, ptStart[i]);` appear unexpectedly. And, in loop api, please aware that `senha` and `linha` are not string type. So using printf with %s for linha and strcmp can cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Likewise (but not, so far, so cause of your segfault, since you don't use it at all), what is `ptStart[0]`? And therefore all the other? `ptStart[0]` is undefined, and all the other are defined after it.

Comment: @ThongDT They _are_ "string" type because, in C, strings are `char` arrays, but need to be 0 terminated. With the fix, they _are_, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Note that _all_ threads are using the _same_ ranges, so all threads duplicate one another. I guess that `ptStart` was intended to solve that, but, even if it was passed as the arg to the thread function, the `loop` function always uses the same hardwired ranges.

Comment: @ThongDT `senha` is `\0` terminated. It is initialized from a string constant, and string constants are `\0` terminated.

Comment: The big issue is that the trial strings (in `linha`) are always the _same_ length. They assume that the password to crack is always 7 chars in length. Good for a start, but, won't work too well generally.

Comment: @CraigEstey what I mean is the neccessary to have `linha[8]=0` in your comments. This to prevent `printf` unexpectedly not stop. Seem we post at same time so it cause your confusion.